# Why does my Rails application always run in Production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

This is Rails 3.0.3.

My deployment is Apache 2.0 with Phusion Passenger. My httpd.conf block looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.mycarparts.co
   DocumentRoot /projects/mcp5/public
   <Directory /projects/mcp5/public>
      AllowOverride all
      Options -MultiViews
      Allow from all                                                                                                                                     
   </Directory>
  RailsEnv staging
</VirtualHost>
```

"Production" is also not specified in my config directory. A grep -i -r yields this:

config/application.rb:# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
config/database.yml:# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
config/database.yml:production:
config/database.yml:    database: mcp_production
config/database.yml:    database: mcp_production
config/environments/production.rb:  # The production environment is meant for finished, "live" apps.
config/environments/production.rb:  # Use a different cache store in production
config/environments/production.rb:  # In production, Apache or nginx will already do this
config/newrelic.yml:  # capitalized RAILS_ENV (i.e., Production, Staging, etc)
config/newrelic.yml:  # Do not use for production or load testing.
config/newrelic.yml:# Turn on the agent in production for 24x7 monitoring.  NewRelic
config/newrelic.yml:production:
config/newrelic.yml:# identically to production.  Support for that environment is provided

These little surprises with the Apache/Passenger/Rails stack are beginning to become irritating. Can anybody help me run my application in the correct mode?

EDIT: I can put:

```
RailsEnv peeweeeffingherman
```

in there and the app still comes up in production mode, which I know is the default. Obviously, the setting is not being read. Why would that be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are on Phusion Passenger < 3.0.2 then RailsEnv only has effect on Rails 1 and Rails 2 apps; Rails 3 apps are considered Rack apps and need RackEnv.

This is a potential source of user confusion so since Phusion Passenger 3, RailsEnv and RackEnv have been made equivalent, and Phusion Passenger sets both RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV. The Nginx version of Phusion Passenger has always worked like that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `rails_env production`?